# How to prove that if an entire function has uncountably many zeroes then it must be constant

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am solving assignment questions of complex analysis which might not be discussed due to pendamic and I was unable to solve this particular question.

> Let f be an entire function that has uncountably many zeroes .  Prove that it is constant.

I was unable to get an idea on which result to use although I am good in complex analysis. So, It's my humble request to you tp kindly guide me.

I thought  of $\prod_{r_i  varies in\in \mathbb{R}} (z-r_i) $ , and I don't know why it must be constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If for each $z\in S\subset\Bbb C$ we find $r_z>0$ such that the open ball $B_{r_z}(z)$contains no point of $S$ other than $z$, then the balls $B_{r_z/2}(z)$ are pairwise disjoint and each contains a point with rational coordinates.

Comment: What is S in 1st line?

Answer (score 0):

Analytic functions which are non-constant are such that their zeroes are isolated, that is, for every zero $z_0$ of $f$ there is a neighborhood $U$ about $z_0$ where $f(z)\not=0$ except if $z=z_0$. We say that the set of zeroes is totally disconnected.

It remains to show that an uncountable set cannot be totally disconnected.

Comment: It is true that the zero set of an entire function is (either $\Bbb C$ or) totally disconnected, but really the characterising property is being *discrete*. All the more because totally disconnected uncountable spaces do exist: see for instance the irrational real numbers, or Cantor's set.